# Pandas drop rows within styles apply function

Tags: python, pandas

I use style.apply function to highlight some cells of the dataframe before printing to excel and want to drop rows which do not have any cells highlighted.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def highlight_difference(x):
    m1 = x['Value_L'] != x['Lim_Low']
    m2 = x['Value_H'] != x['Lim_High']

    df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    df1['Value_L'] = np.where(m1, 'background-color: #E55451', df1['Value_L'])
    df1['Value_H'] = np.where(m2, 'background-color: #E55451', df1['Value_H'])

    drop_mask = m1 | m2
    df1 = df1[drop_mask]

    return df1

df.style.apply(highlight_difference, axis=None).to_excel('Result.xlsx')
```

This will result in following error:

ValueError: Result of <function highlight_difference at 0x000002A6ABD478C8> must have identical index and columns as the input

What would be a reasonable way to solve this problem? Is there even any way to drop the rows within the apply function?

Answer (score 1):

You need remove values before:

```
m1 = df['Value_L'] != df['Lim_Low']
m2 = df['Value_H'] != df['Lim_High']
drop_mask = m1 | m2

df[drop_mask].style.apply(highlight_difference, axis=None).to_excel('Result.xlsx')
```

Also is possible pass DataFrame of styles by this trick:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Value_L':[1,2,3],
                   'Lim_Low':[1,2,3],
                   'Value_H':[1,2,2],
                   'Lim_High':[0,2,3]})


m1 = df['Value_L'] != df['Lim_Low']
m2 = df['Value_H'] != df['Lim_High']
drop_mask = m1 | m2

df11 = df[drop_mask] 
df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=df11.index, columns=df11.columns)
df1['Value_L'] = np.where(m1[drop_mask], 'background-color: #E55451', '')
df1['Value_H'] = np.where(m2[drop_mask], 'background-color: #E55451', '')
print (df1)

df11.style.apply(lambda x: df1, axis=None).to_excel('Result.xlsx')
```